# Rename files in bash keeping the originals unchanged

Tags: bash, shell

I have a folder with a lot of images for a multilingual site, the images are stored in the next format filename.lang_code.jpg, on the deploy script i want to pick the correct one for the site I'm deploying and copy it to filename.jpg so I can share the same css between the sites.

So, what I need is something like the command rename, but performing a copy, not a move, because I need to keep all files.

I'm doing it with the next code, but I find it overcomplicated and awful.

```
find -name "*.es.*" -print0 | xargs --null -I {} sh -c "echo {} | sed 's/.es//' | xargs -I }{ sh -c 'cp {} }{'"
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using (symbolic) links?

Comment: Have you considered softlinks instead of copies? That would save a lot of diskspace and time.

Comment: Yes, I could use softlinks to save space, in fact i will :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -name '*.es.*' -exec bash -c 'cp "$1" "${1/.es./.}"' modlang {} \;
```

Comment: why not consider using xargs or +; (GNU find) ?.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of copying/renaming is usually easier to perform in zsh, where you don't need to write a `for` loop or `find` command.

```
zmv -Ls '(**)/(*).es.(*)' '$1/$2.$3'
```

The `-Ls` is to create symbolic links; replace by `-C` for a copy, or nothing for a move. Other useful options are `-i` (ask for confirmation for each copy/move) and `-n` (just show what would happen but don't actually perform the copies/moves).

The `$1`, `$2`, `$3` in the replacement text refer to the first, second and third parenthesized group in the pattern. In the pattern, `**/` means any chain of directories.

You may need to first load the `zmv` command with `autoload zmv`. This can usefully go into your `.zshrc`, as well as `alias zcp='zmv -L'` and `alias zln='zmv -L'`.

Answer (score 1):

bash 4

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **/*.es*
do
  newfilename=${file/.es/}
  cp "$file" ""$newfilename"
done
```

of using find

```
find . -type f -iname "*.es.*" -print | sed 's/\(.*\)\.es\.\(.*\)/mv \1.es.\2 \1\2/' |bash
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a for loop?

```
for x in *.es.* ; do
  xx=$(echo ${x} | sed 's/\.es//')
  cp ${x} ${xx}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. you could just copy the whole lot of jpg's you want, put them in the directory you need them and just rename them from there?

Something like:

```
cp *.jpg /src /dst
cd /dst && rename 's/\.es//' *.jpg
```

The rename command is a wrapper for a perl script.